# How to find eigenvectors/eigenvalues of a matrix where each diagonal entry is scalar $d$ and all other entries are $1$

Tags: linear-algebra

How would you find eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a $n\times n$ matrix where each diagonal entry is scalar $d$ and all other entries are $1$ ? I am looking for a decomposition but cannot find anything for this. 
For example:

$\begin{pmatrix}2&1&1&1\\1&2&1&1\\1&1&2&1\\1&1&1&2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: You should have clarified your original question; finding exact eigenvectors / eigenvalues of structured matrices as opposed to finding approximate eigenvectors / eigenvalues of arbitrary matrices are _very different_ problems.

Comment: they are different questions. one requires a general process of finding eigenvectors while this is specific to this matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The matrix is $(d-1)I + J$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $J$ is the all-ones matrix, so once you have the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $J$ the eigenvectors of $(d-1)I + J$ are the same and the eigenvalues are each $d-1$ greater.  (Convince yourself that this works.)

But $J$ has rank $1$, so it has eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$.  The last eigenvalue is $n$, and it's quite easy to write down all the eigenvectors.

Comment: It really should be hammered often enough: exploit any structure you find in your problem to the hilt.